# Sql injection on stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to do sql injection on my stored procedure through login form.
Here is my stored procedure

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[sp_ADM_Login] 
    @loginName varchar(25),
    @password varchar(100)
)

AS

select
    l.LoginId,
    l.LoginName,
    l.LoginType,
    l.RG_cCode,
    dbo.GetUserName(l.UserDetailsCode, l.LoginType) as [Name],
    isnull(l.DefBranchId, 0) as BranchId,
l.DefBranchCode as branchCode,
l.LoginCode as loginCode
from   
    ADM_Login l 
where  
    LoginName = @loginName and
    [Password] = @password and
    l.IsActive = 1
```

I tried giving user name to `user' or 1=1--`
But it doesn't work. Is it possible to do sql injection in this code?

To executing store procedure, Here is C# code

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
    DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_ADM_Login");
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@loginName", DbType.String, loginName);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@password", DbType.String, password);
    DbDataReader dr = (DbDataReader)db.ExecuteReader(cmd);
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible when you use parameter. :)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to do SQL injection with properly parameterized queries, as long as you call them from your C# code with parameters. If you format an `EXEC sp_ADM_login...` SQL string by yourself you are vulnerable.

With the C# code using proper parameters as you do you are totally safe. Any strange values will be properly escaped.

Comment: Actually, not completely true. If you use parameters as part of a string concatenation inside your dynamic query, you are still vulnerable to injection, because your strings will not be escaped but will be literal. Using other types for parameters (such as integer) is safe.

Comment: Yes you're right that there is a risk, but not in the SP shown here. @troyhunt has a great post on it: http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/12/stored-procedures-and-orms-wont-save.html

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to do SQL injection when you are using parameters to pass information to your stored procedure from the code.

SQL Injection can happen if you concatenate queries from string parts and not use parameters.